# How to listen to changes of an signal that contains a set in preact (using signal.value.has...)

Tags: signals, preact

In the follwoing minimal example I would like to change the buttons' text, after the click event.
The button-ids that have been clicked, are stored in a set within a signal. When the set changes, no dom-update is triggered.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
import { render } from 'preact';
import { signal, effect } from "@preact/signals-core";


export function App() {

    const selected = signal(new Set<number>);

    const onClick = (index) =>{
        console.log("click" + index +" current state:"+ selected.value.has(index))
        const s = new Set(selected.value)
        if(selected.value.has(index))
            s.delete(index)
        else
            s.add(index)

        selected.value = s
    }


    return (
        <div>
            <div>
            {new Array(10).fill(0).map((_, index) => (
                <button type="button" onClick={() => onClick(index)}>
                    {selected.value.has(index)+""}
                </button>
            ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    );

}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should be using `@preact/signals`, not `@preact/signals-core`, in a Preact app. The former adds bindings that you need.

Secondly,  you cannot use `signal` inside of a component. Use `useSignal()` if you cannot extract out the signal creation.

> When creating signals within a component, use the hook variant: `useSignal(initialValue)`.

https://preactjs.com/guide/v10/signals#signalinitialvalue

After that, it should work:

```js
import { render } from 'preact';
import { useSignal } from '@preact/signals';

export function App() {
  const selected = useSignal(new Set<number>);

  const onClick = (index) => {
    console.log(
      'click' + index + ' current state:' + selected.value.has(index)
    );
    const s = new Set(selected.value);
    if (selected.value.has(index)) s.delete(index);
    else s.add(index);

    selected.value = s;
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {new Array(10).fill(0).map((_, index) => (
          <button type="button" onClick={() => onClick(index)}>
            {selected.value.has(index) + ''}
          </button>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```